# Count Sort Algorithm efficiency

Tags: algorithms, sorting

As I read a book about "Algorithm Analysis", I came across `count_sort` Algorithm. 
However, I have read elsewhere that "Quick Sort/ Merge Sort" are the best and the most efficient sorting algorithms. I found this confusing because the complexity of `count_sort` is `O(n+k)`, which is better than Mergesort and Quicksort which are O(n ln n).

My question:

- What is the problem with this sorting Algorithm?
- What are the best sorting Algorithms?

  ```
  def count_sort(seq):
      b, c = [], defaultdict(list)
      for x in seq:
          c[x].append(x)

      for k in range(min(c), max(c)+1):
          b.extend(c[k])
      return b
  ```

Comment: Why do you say that this is O(n+k)? How do you think `defaultdict` is implemented?

Comment: defaultdict is a python package check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-collections-defaultdict-work

Comment: Yes, I know what defaultdict is. However, using it is not free in terms of complexity.

Comment: True ! I wanted to illustrate how can we build sort algo in a very quick way. But still that we can remplace it with L= [{x:x} for x in list seq]

Comment: Most of the time you are sorting things that are not integers, and only have a `<` to order them by. Counting sort can only be "better" when it is *applicable*

Answer (score 6):

Counting sorts fail when there are large key values (the k in the O(n)). This means that if you have a large variety of key values, counting sort will be slow. Radix sort can help solve that problem but it does nothing for other issue. Both counting and [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) are only valid for integer keys. While not a terribly serious limitation, it does mean that Radix Sort's value for the number of digits in a key should not be considered constant.

There's also the small matter of space complexity and stability of sorting. Radix sort requires a stable sorting algorithm to be used as a subsort. Counting sort is stable, provided that you use a separate input and output structure. If you don't then you wind up with an unstable sort. That is, you may wind up with elements in the wrong order.

"Best" is a very loaded term. There is no "best" sorting algorithm. It will depend on a variety of factors including time complexity, space complexity, ability to parallelize the implementation and the ease of implementation.

Comment: Radix sort is not limited to integers.  Read the first paragraph of that Wikipedia article you linked.

Comment: They are only valid for integer keys as stated, which can map to a variety of value types also as stated.